# How to import and print seperate txt file in spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import several text files into my Spyder file, which I want to add to a list later on.

why does

`test1 = open("test1.txt")`

result in test1 as "TextIOWrapper"? How would I bring the content over into the python file?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the lines into your list after opening it. For example, the code should be:

```py
with open('test1.txt') as f:
     test1= f.readlines()
```

The above code will read the contents of your text file into the list `test1`. However, if the data in your text file is separated over multiple lines, the escape char '\n' will be included in your list.

To avoid this, use the below refined code:

```py
test1= [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('test1.txt')]
```

Comment: @Lana_Del_Neigh Do accept and upvote if this answer has solved your problem!